# VS Emulator for Android doesn't create emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

Week ago I created Android vms and I was able to run from Hyper-v window but i wasn't able to run from VS for Android. Yesterday I removed all vms from Hyper-v becouse i had problems with Windows Phone virtual machines. Now I have luckly working Windows Phone machines but I cant make any Android machines becouse every time when I create new machine VS for Android freeze on "Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine". I tried to reinstall VS Emulator for Android but it doesnt help. What I have to do for fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happend to me as well, and it very easy to fix this


uninstall visual studio emulator for android
restart your pc/laptop
download and install fresh copy of visual studio emulator for android


let me if this works for you
Feel Free to ask if any error occurs